# Drag context menu with Parent

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this simple login from with ContextMenu which is displayed as validator message:

```
public class MainApp extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        stage.setTitle("Validation Demo");
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        borderPane.setCenter(loadLoginScreen());
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 700, 500);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(
            MainApp.class.getResource("/styles/context.css")
            .toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private GridPane loadLoginScreen()
    {

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        Text scenetitle = new Text("Welcome");
        scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

        Label userName = new Label("User Name:");
        grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

        final TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);

        Label pw = new Label("Password:");
        grid.add(pw, 0, 2);

        final PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
        grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);

        Button btn = new Button("Sign in");
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
        grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);

        final Text actiontarget = new Text();
        grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

        // Context Menu for error messages
        final ContextMenu usernameValidator = new ContextMenu();


        usernameValidator.setAutoHide(false);
        final ContextMenu passValidator = new ContextMenu();
        passValidator.setAutoHide(false);

        // Action on button press
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // Clearing message if any
                actiontarget.setText("");

                // Checking if the userTextField is empty
                if (userTextField.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    usernameValidator.getItems().clear();
                    usernameValidator.getItems().add(
                        new MenuItem("Please enter username Please enter username Please enter username Please enter username Please enter username"));
                    usernameValidator.show(userTextField, Side.RIGHT, 10, 0);
                }
                // Checking if the pwBox is empty
                if (pwBox.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    passValidator.getItems().clear();
                    passValidator.getItems().add(
                        new MenuItem("Please enter Password"));
                    passValidator.show(pwBox, Side.RIGHT, 10, 0);
                }
                // If both of the above textFields have values
                if (!pwBox.getText().equals("")
                    && !userTextField.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    actiontarget.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                    actiontarget.setText("Welcome");
                }
            }
        });

        userTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
            {
                @Override
                public void changed(
                    ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
                {
                    if (newPropertyValue)
                    {
                        // Clearing message if any
                        actiontarget.setText("");
                        // Hiding the error message
                        usernameValidator.hide();
                    }
                    }
            });

        pwBox.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
            {
                if (newPropertyValue)
                {
                    // Clearing message if any
                    actiontarget.setText("");
                    // Hiding the error message
                    passValidator.hide();
                }
            }
        });
        return grid;
    }

}
```

I noticed that when I drag the window the validatoin messages are not dragged with the parent window. Can I somehow fix this? I would like to drag the login form and also the ContextMenu.

Comment: Showing the validation message in text or label can be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes but many of the windows where I'm using validation popup massage are too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is a fix. Also included Uluk's suggestion (just on username) to use a popup which is basically the same as your idea. Note that this fix doesn't cater for resizing the Stage.

```
public class MainApp extends Application
{
    private Popup usernameValidator;
    private ContextMenu passValidator;

    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception
    {
        stage.setTitle( "Validation Demo" );
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        borderPane.setCenter( loadLoginScreen() );
        Scene scene = new Scene( borderPane, 700, 500 );
        scene.getStylesheets().add(MainApp.class.getResource("/styles/context.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();

        stage.xProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Number>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number oldX, Number newX )
            {
                double delta = oldX.doubleValue() - newX.doubleValue();

                if ( usernameValidator.isShowing() ) adjustX( usernameValidator, delta );
                if ( passValidator.isShowing() ) adjustX( passValidator, delta );
            }

            private void adjustX( PopupWindow menu, double delta )
            {
                menu.setX( menu.getX() - delta );
            }
        } );

        stage.yProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Number>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number oldY, Number newY )
            {
                double delta = oldY.doubleValue() - newY.doubleValue();

                if ( usernameValidator.isShowing() ) adjustY( usernameValidator, delta );
                if ( passValidator.isShowing() ) adjustY( passValidator, delta );
            }

            private void adjustY( PopupWindow menu, double delta )
            {
                menu.setY( menu.getY() - delta );
            }
        } );

        stage.focusedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean wasFocused, Boolean isFocused )
            {
                if ( wasFocused && ! isFocused )
                {
                    if ( usernameValidator.isShowing() ) usernameValidator.hide();
                    if ( passValidator.isShowing() ) passValidator.hide();
                }
            }
        } );

        stage.setResizable( false );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch( args );
    }

    private GridPane loadLoginScreen()
    {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER );
        grid.setHgap( 10 );
        grid.setVgap( 10 );
        grid.setPadding( new Insets( 25, 25, 25, 25 ) );

        Text scenetitle = new Text( "Welcome" );
        scenetitle.setFont( Font.font( "Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20 ) );
        grid.add( scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1 );

        Label userName = new Label( "User Name:" );
        grid.add( userName, 0, 1 );

        final TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add( userTextField, 1, 1 );

        Label pw = new Label( "Password:" );
        grid.add( pw, 0, 2 );

        final PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
        grid.add( pwBox, 1, 2 );

        Button btn = new Button( "Sign in" );
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox( 10 );
        hbBtn.setAlignment( Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT );
        hbBtn.getChildren().add( btn );
        grid.add( hbBtn, 1, 4 );

        final Text actiontarget = new Text();
        grid.add( actiontarget, 1, 6 );

        // Context Menu for error messages
        // usernameValidator = new ContextMenu();
        // usernameValidator.setAutoHide(false);
        usernameValidator = new Popup();
        passValidator = new ContextMenu();
        passValidator.setAutoHide( false );

        Label mesaj = new Label( "Please enter Username" );
        mesaj.setStyle( "-fx-background-color:#FCFBBD; -fx-padding: 5; -fx-border-color: #BFBD3B" );
        usernameValidator.getContent().add( mesaj );

        // Action on button press
        btn.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle( ActionEvent e )
            {
                // Clearing message if any
                actiontarget.setText( "" );

                // Checking if the userTextField is empty
                if ( userTextField.getText().equals( "" ) )
                {
                    double  x, y;
                    Window  win = userTextField.getScene().getWindow();
                    x = win.getX() + userTextField.localToScene( 0, 0 ).getX() + userTextField.getScene().getX() + userTextField.getWidth();
                    y = win.getY() + userTextField.localToScene( 0, 0 ).getY() + userTextField.getScene().getY();
                    usernameValidator.show( userTextField, x, y );
                }
                // Checking if the pwBox is empty
                if ( pwBox.getText().equals( "" ) )
                {
                    passValidator.getItems().clear();
                    passValidator.getItems().add(
                            new MenuItem( "Please enter Password" ) );
                    passValidator.show( pwBox, Side.RIGHT, 10, 0 );
                }
                // If both of the above textFields have values
                if ( !pwBox.getText().equals( "" )
                        && !userTextField.getText().equals( "" ) )
                {
                    actiontarget.setFill( Color.GREEN );
                    actiontarget.setText( "Welcome" );
                }
            }
        } );

        userTextField.focusedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue )
            {
                if ( newPropertyValue )
                {
                    // Clearing message if any
                    actiontarget.setText( "" );
                    // Hiding the error message
                    usernameValidator.hide();
                }
            }
        } );

        pwBox.focusedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue )
            {
                if ( newPropertyValue )
                {
                    // Clearing message if any
                    actiontarget.setText( "" );
                    // Hiding the error message
                    passValidator.hide();
                }
            }
        } );

        return grid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good! There is a just small detail which I need to ask how to could be solved. When I display the Context menu with the error message the Context Menu is always on top even when I switch the application windows. How I can hide it? Try to display error message and switch the Java application with the web browser window.

Comment: @user1285928 Ok, added focus lost listener to stage.

Comment: @user1285928  Also have a look at: [ControlsFX PopOver](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#popover)

Answer (score 1):

Using `ContextMenu` for showing validation messages does not fit well. Instead I suggest to use its sibling node, the `Popup` control.

```
final Popup usernameValidator = new Popup();
```

Show it with its owner control after calculating the appropriate coordinates. Also you need to update this coordinate on every change of local bounds of the owner node.

```
Label mesaj = new Label("Please enter username");
mesaj.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#FCFBBD; -fx-padding: 5; -fx-border-color: #BFBD3B");
usernameValidator.getContent().add(mesaj);
userTextField.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(
        (ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable, Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) -> {
    Bounds bounds = userTextField.localToScreen(userTextField.getBoundsInLocal());
    usernameValidator.show(userTextField, bounds.getMaxX(), bounds.getMinY());
});
Bounds bounds = userTextField.localToScreen(userTextField.getBoundsInLocal());
usernameValidator.show(userTextField, bounds.getMaxX(), bounds.getMinY());
```

These codes are here to give you the idea, code refactoring and optimization left up to you, like generalization of the methods and dealing only with the related parts of changed local bounds etc.

Comment: Could you please update the answer with complete working example. I don't have enough knowledge to complete it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two alternative and less complicated ways of doing it. Since you have size constraints maybe the password version would suit your needs better.

```
public class MainApp2 extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception
    {
        stage.setTitle( "Validation Demo" );
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        borderPane.setCenter( loadLoginScreen() );
        Scene scene = new Scene( borderPane, 700, 500 );
        scene.getStylesheets().add(MainApp.class.getResource("/styles/context.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        launch( args );
    }

    private GridPane loadLoginScreen()
    {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER );
        grid.setHgap( 10 );
        grid.setVgap( 10 );
        grid.setPadding( new Insets( 25, 25, 25, 25 ) );

        Text scenetitle = new Text( "Welcome" );
        scenetitle.setFont( Font.font( "Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20 ) );
        grid.add( scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1 );

        Label userName = new Label( "User Name:" );
        grid.add( userName, 0, 1 );

        final TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add( userTextField, 1, 1 );

        final Label usernameValidator = new Label("Please enter Username");
        usernameValidator.setStyle( "-fx-background-color:#FCFBBD; -fx-padding: 5; -fx-border-color: #BFBD3B" );
        usernameValidator.setVisible( false );
        usernameValidator.setManaged( false );
        grid.add( usernameValidator, 2, 1 );

        Label pw = new Label( "Password:" );
        grid.add( pw, 0, 2 );

        final PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
        grid.add( pwBox, 1, 2 );

        Button btn = new Button( "Sign in" );
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox( 10 );
        hbBtn.setAlignment( Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT );
        hbBtn.getChildren().add( btn );
        grid.add( hbBtn, 1, 4 );

        final Text actiontarget = new Text();
        grid.add( actiontarget, 1, 6 );


        // Action on button press
        btn.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle( ActionEvent e )
            {
                // Clearing message if any
                actiontarget.setText( "" );

                // Checking if the userTextField is empty
                if ( userTextField.getText().equals( "" ) )
                {
                    usernameValidator.setVisible( true );
                    usernameValidator.setManaged( true );
                }

                // Checking if the pwBox is empty
                if ( pwBox.getText().equals( "" ) )
                {
                    pwBox.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: orangered, derive(orangered,80%); -fx-prompt-text-fill: purple;" );
                    pwBox.setPromptText( "Please enter Password" );
                }
                // If both of the above textFields have values
                if ( !pwBox.getText().equals( "" )
                        && !userTextField.getText().equals( "" ) )
                {
                    actiontarget.setFill( Color.GREEN );
                    actiontarget.setText( "Welcome" );
                }
            }
        } );

        userTextField.focusedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue )
            {
                if ( newPropertyValue )
                {
                    // Clearing message if any
                    actiontarget.setText( "" );
                    // Hiding the error message
                    usernameValidator.setVisible( false );
                    usernameValidator.setManaged( false );
                }
            }
        } );

        pwBox.focusedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue )
            {
                if ( newPropertyValue )
                {
                    // Clearing message if any
                    actiontarget.setText( "" );
                    // Hiding the error message
                    pwBox.setStyle( null );
                }
            }
        } );

        return grid;
    }
}
```